# Adding HTML and JS (with event listeners) to a page via Chrome API for Chrome Extensions

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, addeventlistener, content-script

I'm working on creating a Chrome extension, and I'm having trouble with adding a button with an onclick event listener to a page using Chrome Content Scripts. I did look at a lot of similar posts, including [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9515704/insert-code-into-the-page-context-using-a-content-script) which suggests injecting scripts. I injected a script to my content script, and everything I have in the injected script (creating the button on the content page) works, except creating the event listener - nothing happens when I click on the button.
My content script injects a script to manipulate the DOM of the page:

```
function injectScript() {
 const s = document.createElement('script');
 s.src = chrome.runtime.getURL('readlater.js'); //my inject script
 (document.head || document.documentElement).appendChild(s);
 s.remove();
}
```

And the injected script creates a button & an event listener:

```
const btn = document.createElement('button');
btn.setAttribute('id', 'mybtn');
btn.innerHTML = 'click me!';
document.body.append(btn);
console.log(document.getElementById('mybtn')); //the elt is found
document.getElementById('mybtn').addEventListener('click', function () {
  alert('clicked!');
});
```

I added the inject script to manifest.json, like so: `"web_accessible_resources": ["readlater.js"]`.
The button (or any html I tried) is being created, however, clicking on the button is never registered by the listener. What is the right way of setting up event listeners? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You have to tweak this a bit;

```
document.getElementById('mybtn').addEventListener('click', function () {
  alert('clicked!');
})
```

to be;

```
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    if (e.target.matches('#mybtn')) {
        alert('clicked!');
    }
});
```

That way you can listen for dynamic content. This way it checks for the element upon click rather than on load. I think this is what you are after?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! That also didn't work unfortunately.

Comment: Are you able to put together a sample in a fiddle or codepen and I can take a look? That should work.

Comment: Here is a fiddle I put together to show. I've added comments as notes; https://jsfiddle.net/daobvj2h/1/ - In this example, it creates 2 images and you will notice one listener doesn't work where the other does. Excuse my rough mock-up.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - actually, the code I have by itself also works on a fiddle/on codepen. I think that this problem is specifically related to Chrome Content Scripts, rather than the JS/HTML.

Comment: You might be right. I remember in some chrome extensions I made that I had similar issues and either had to come up with a convoluted work around or drop the function entirely. Sorry this didn't help :(

Comment: Thanks anyways, I will update the post if I find a slightly different approach for it!